# Why is exponentiation ** different from pow() ? - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

In python `2**3` equates to `pow(2,3)`
but somehow `-1**0` is not equal to `pow(-1,0)`
The first gives an unexpected output of **-1** ?

Can somebody explain why ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`**` takes precedence over the `-`, so your code is being evaluated like this:

```
  -(1**0)
= -(1)
= -1
```

To get the same answer, add parentheses:

```
(-1)**0
```

The documentation explains the `**` operator a little more right here: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator

Comment: yes, it's just simple math, order of operations, which I think is taugth in the primary school :)